Activate Ubuntu pro subscription
How to activate Ubuntu Pro subscription on a system that can reach internet only via proxy?
Tried the commands ua attach <subscription_id>, but, it didn't go through.
The ua status output is throwing the error below:
Failed to connect to https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/resources?architecture=amd64&kernel=5.4.0-190-generic&series=focal&virt=vmware
Is there any first level login attempt needs to be performed to activate the subscription? The URL is whitelisted at Proxy level for the system to go through.
The server is non-internet facing and is fronted by forward proxy to route request to internet. In my case, the ubuntu URLs are whitelisted to pass through

Not sure what your issue is. I use VPN 100 percent of the time and Pro works on that machine as well as machines not using VPN.

The server is non-internet facing and is fronted by forward proxy to route request to internet. In my case, the ubuntu URLs are whitelisted to pass through

I think there is info on that on the Ubuntu Pro site.
